# WPF Selecting background color

Tags: c#, wpf, background

Ok, so I just tried out the WPF [WPF Example from msdn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXWXM.png), and I noticed it says you get a dropdown menu, but I only get a dropdown menu if I go to the xaml code itself.
And even then when selecting brown, it shows some darkish red color, what is up with that?

### Question:

How to get the default brown color.

### Code:

Sorry forgot the Xaml code..

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Ink_Pane.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Ink Pane" Height="550" Width="370">
<Grid Background="Brown" Height="520" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" Margin="9,9,10,68" Background="LightYellow"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnClear" Content="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,457,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" Height="39" Click="btnClear_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnClose" Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="202,457,9,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="39" Click="btnClose_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

### EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Atleast explain the downvote, I know its a noob question but it isn't mentioned...

Comment: So your asking why the background is red when you have set it to brown?  Could you post your xaml code

Comment: @RobJohnson Yes and if the reason is because you can select differend default colors, the default colors in WPF are different than the standard colors, blue,green,yellow,red etc are all the "flashy" colors...

Comment: I agree that the brown looks more like red, this appears to be due to microsofts definition of brown rather than your code though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors.aspx Sorry I dont really understand your question, what do you mean by flashy colours?

Comment: MSDN used "SaddleBrown" instead of the standard "Brown". It must just be a typo.

Comment: @RobJohnson By flashy colors, its just that the default colors used now are realy bright, like markers, I was just wondering if there isn't a setting that uses darker variant of that color, so you don't always have to find darker color. But it seems you just have to find it in the dropdown, or either select your own by rbg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Properties Window]

Is this what your properties window looks like?

MSDN must have meant `SaddleBrown` because yes, the standard `Brown` has a red tint to it.

Comment: I meant saddlebrown instead of the other brown, I just found it odd for the reddish since I've never had that color when using brown before..

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2012 & In winform I get the dropdown menu to select colors from web or just typing in a color. But in WPF I don't have any default colors, neither in system resources, only the XAML dropdown..

Comment: Did you select the `Solid Color` widget first? After selecting `Solid Color` the drop down box appears. (See my screenshot)

Comment: Yes I did, if you look at the edit screenshot, the solid color is selected

Comment: And you still cannot select any default colors from the drop down?

Comment: Nope no dropdown, only in xaml code..., there's only the extra choice for opacity or selecting HEX..

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate SP1, VS 2012 Ultimate

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23784/discussion-between-csharp-student-and-jordan-carroll)